# Lock-free, awaitable, exclusive access methods

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, lock-free, interlocked

I have a thread safe class which uses a particular resource that needs to be accessed exclusively. In my assessment it does not make sense to have the callers of various methods block on a `Monitor.Enter` or await a `SemaphoreSlim` in order to access this resource.

For instance I have some "expensive" asynchronous initialization. Since it does not make sense to initialize more than once, whether it be from multiple threads or a single one, multiple calls should return immediately (or even throw an exception). Instead one should create, init and *then* distribute the instance to multiple threads.

**UPDATE 1:**

`MyClass` uses two `NamedPipes` in either direction. The `InitBeforeDistribute` method is not really initialization, but rather properly setting up a connection in both directions. It does not make sense to make the pipe available to `N` threads before you have set up the connection. Once it is setup multiple threads can post work, but only one can actually read/write to the stream. My apologies for obfuscating this with poor naming of the examples.

**UPDATE 2:**

If `InitBeforeDistribute` implemented a `SemaphoreSlim(1, 1)` with proper await logic (instead of the interlocked operation throwing an exception), is the Add/Do Square method OK practice? It does not throw a redundant exception (such as in `InitBeforeDistribute`), while being lock-free?

The following would be a <del>good</del> bad example:

```
class MyClass
{
    private int m_isIniting = 0; // exclusive access "lock"
    private volatile bool vm_isInited = false; // vol. because other methods will read it

    public async Task InitBeforeDistribute()
    {
        if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.m_isIniting, -1) != 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "Cannot init concurrently! Did you distribute before init was finished?");

        try
        {
            if (this.vm_isInited)
                return;

            await Task.Delay(5000)      // init asynchronously
                .ConfigureAwait(false);

            this.vm_isInited = true;
        }
        finally
        {
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.m_isConnecting, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Some points:

1. If there is a case where blocking/awaiting access to a lock makes
   perfect sense, then this example does not (make sense, that is).
2. Since I need to await in the method, I must use something like a
   SemaphoreSlim if I where to use a "proper" lock. Forgoing the
   Semaphore for the example above allows me to not worry about
   disposing the class once I'm done with it. (I always disliked the
   idea of disposing an item used by multiple threads. This is a *minor*
   positive, for sure.)
3. If the method is called often there might be some performance
   benefits, which of course should be measured.

The above example does not make sense in ref. to (3.) so here is another example:

```
class MyClass
{
    private volatile bool vm_isInited = false; // see above example
    private int m_isWorking = 0; // exclusive access "lock"
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<Tuple<int, TaskCompletionSource<int>> m_squareWork =
        new ConcurrentQueue<Tuple<int, TaskCompletionSource<int>>();

    public Task<int> AddSquare(int number)
    {
        if (!this.vm_isInited) // see above example
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "You forgot to init! Did you already distribute?");

        var work = new Tuple<int, TaskCompletionSource<int>(number, new TaskCompletionSource<int>()
        this.m_squareWork.Enqueue(work);

        Task do = DoSquare();

        return work.Item2.Task;
    }

    private async Task DoSquare()
    {
        if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.m_isWorking, -1) != 0)
            return; // let someone else do the work for you

        do
        {
            try
            {
                Tuple<int, TaskCompletionSource<int> work;

                while (this.m_squareWork.TryDequeue(out work))
                {
                    await Task.Delay(5000)      // Limiting resource that can only be
                        .ConfigureAwait(false); // used by one thread at a time.

                    work.Item2.TrySetResult(work.Item1 * work.Item1);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.m_isWorking, 0);
            }
        } while (this.m_squareWork.Count != 0 &&
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.m_isWorking, -1) == 0)
    }
}
```

Are there some of the specific negative aspects of this "lock-free" example that I should pay attention to?

Most questions relating to "lock-free" code on SO generally advise against it, stating that it is for the "experts". Rarely (I could be wrong on this one) do I see suggestions for books/blogs/etc that one can delve into, should one be so inclined. If there any such resources I should look into, please share. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Why do prefer throwing an exception instead of simply awaiting a task until its completed?

Comment: So, to make sure I understand you... you have an expensive initialization procedure, which is invoked when the first thread accesses the resource. What is the use case for subsequent threads that try to access the resource? From your post, it sounds like you want them to throw exceptions or return immediately (without getting data?), neither of which sounds more appropriate that simply blocking until the initialization is complete. Am I missing something? When something needs exclusive access, that sounds like the exact use case for a lock.

Comment: [`AsyncLock`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncLock) is your friend. Don't overthink this.

Comment: I may be missing something here, but why aren't you simply using [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the thread-safe initialization?

Comment: @i3arnon I suppose the question would be: "is this an OK pattern" and what books do you suggest I read more about what I need to keep in mind when doing this. Perhaps this is too unspecific to be on SO, in which case I apologize.

Comment: @LaFleur my answer would be no, this is a bad pattern. If you want to look into synchronization constructs start with Stephen Toub's excellent series about [Building Async Coordination Primitives](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/11/10266920.aspx)

Comment: The first piece of code is fine if you really want to fail threads coming in after the first one. I don't know why that would be a good thing but it will work. What is code piece #2 supposed to accomplish? A work queue?

Comment: @LaFleur: I'll assume you're already familiar with threading and synchronization primitives. The hardest part of lock-free programming is not writing the code; it's proving that the code is correct within your memory model. The best resources are probably Joe Duffy's book and blog, and I believe cbrumme had some good ones, too. Fun fact: the .NET specification memory model and actual .NET memory model are significantly different. Note that you'll probably spend more time learning about memory models than all your users combined will ever save.

Comment: On a side note, I can't think of a single use case where "lock-free" and "asynchronous" make sense together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: great article related

[.: Creating High-Performance Locks and Lock-free Code (for .NET) :.](http://www.adammil.net/blog/v111_Creating_High-Performance_Locks_and_Lock-free_Code_for_NET_.html)

---

1. The main point about `lock-free` algorythms is not that they are for `experts`.
   The main point is `Do you really need lock-free algorythm here?` I can't understand your logic here:

   > Since it does not make sense to initialize more than once, whether it be from multiple threads or a single one, **multiple calls should return immediately** (or even throw an exception).

   Why can't your users simply wait for a result of initialization, and use your resource after that? If your can, simply use the `Lazy<T>` class or even [`Asynchronous Lazy Initialization`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/asynchronous-lazy-initialization.html).
2. You really should read about [consensus number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_%28computer_science%29) and [CAS-operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) and why does it matters while implementing your own synchronization primitive.

   In your code your are using the `Interlocked.Exchange` method, which isn't `CAS` in real, as it **always** exchanges the value, and it has a consensus number equal to `2`. This means that the primitive using such construction will work correctly only for `2` threads (not in your situation, but still `2`).

   I've tried to define is your code works correctly for `3` threads, or there can be some circumstances which lead your application to damaged state, but after `30` minutes I stopped. And any your team member will stop like me after some time trying to understand your code. This is a waste of time, not only yours, but your team. Don't reinvent the wheel until you really have to.
3. My favorite book in related area is [Writing High-Performance .NET Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00LR30G4O) by Ben Watson, and my favorite blog is [Stephen Cleary](http://blog.stephencleary.com/)'s. If you can be more specific about what kind of book are you interested in, I can add some more references.
4. No locks in program doesn't make your application `lock-free`. In .NET application you really should not use the `Exceptions` for your internal program flow. Consider that the initializing thread isn't scheduled for a while by the OS (on various reasons, no matter what they are exactly).

   In this case all other threads in your app will die step by step trying to access your shared resource. I can't say that this is a `lock-free` code. Yes, there are no locks in it, but **it doesn't guarantee the correctness of the program and thus it isn't a lock-free by definition**.

Comment: Thanks! I want to read up on these things (threading/performance) in general, this is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

**The Art of Multiprocessor Programming by Maurice Herlihy and Nir Shavit**, is a great resource for lock-free and wait-free programming. lock-free is a progress guarantee other than a mode of programming, so to argue that an algorithm is lock-free, one has to validate or show proofs of the progress guarantee. lock-free in simple terms implies that blocking or halting of one thread doesn't not block progress of other threads or that if a threads is blocked infinitely often, then there is another thread that makes progress infinitely often.

Comment: The suggested book is not .NET specific, which is positive for wider understanding. Thank you!